# Neo4j - "CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('" - error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This code loads fine but was taking a while so I decided to go with the apoc periodic load.  I added the `CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('` to the beginning and `',{batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true})` to the end.  But am having issues with an error.

```
// URL ONLY
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('
                    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/4_hour_parsed_and_ready.csv") AS row
                    MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld})
                    MERGE (b:Link { name: row.Url_Sub_Fld, topLevelDomain: row.Url_Tld, htmlEncodedMessage: row.HTML_Encoded})
                    MERGE (c:Recipient { name: row.To})
                    WITH a,b,c,row
                    WHERE row.FileName = "false" AND NOT row.Url_Tld = "false"
                    CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel as rel1
                    CALL apoc.merge.relationship(b, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, c) YIELD rel as rel2
                    RETURN a,b,c
                    ',{batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true})
```

I am running into the error:

`Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Procedure call does not provide the required number of arguments: got 2 expected 3.`

`Procedure apoc.periodic.iterate has signature: apoc.periodic.iterate(cypherIterate :: STRING?, cypherAction :: STRING?, config :: MAP?) :: batches :: INTEGER?, total :: INTEGER?, timeTaken :: INTEGER?, committedOperations :: INTEGER?, failedOperations :: INTEGER?, failedBatches :: INTEGER?, retries :: INTEGER?, errorMessages :: MAP?, batch :: MAP?, operations :: MAP?, wasTerminated :: BOOLEAN?, failedParams :: MAP?
meaning that it expects 3 arguments of type STRING?, STRING?, MAP?
Description: apoc.periodic.iterate('statement returning items', 'statement per item', {batchSize:1000,iterateList:true,parallel:false,params:{},concurrency:50,retries:0}) YIELD batches, total - run the second statement for each item returned by the first statement. Returns number of batches and total processed rows (line 2, column 1 (offset: 12))
"CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('"
             ^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, [apoc.periodic.iterate](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/cypher-execution/commit-batching/) takes 2 Cypher statements (plus the config options). You are only supplying 1 statement. Read the documentation for more details.

However, you should be aware that `LOAD CSV` supports [transaction batching](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/export-import/load-csv/#_transaction_batching) via `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`. So, instead of running your query within `apoc.periodic.iterate`, you can try prepending `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000` to your `LOAD CSV` clause.

*By the way, the [transaction batching](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/export-import/load-csv/#_transaction_batching) section of the docs also shows one way to use `apoc.periodic.iterate` as well.*